How to use confusionMatrix in R
logit_cm <- confusionMatrix(data=logitresp, reference=actual)

logit <- glm(Outcome ~ ., family = binomial (link = logit),
                             data = training_data)

Returns:
Error: data and reference should be factors with the same levels.
They are of the same number of lines and same data type, I don't know why caret wont work with them.
For:
> str(logitresp)
num [1:384] 0.1128 0.0964 0.3948 0.4793 0.4889 ...

> str(actual)
num [1:384] 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 ...

dput(training_data)
structure(list(Pregnancies = c(6, 1, 8, 1, 0, 5, 3, 10, 2, 8, 
4, 10, 10, 1, 5, 7, 0, 7, 1, 1, 3, 8, 7, 9, 11, 10, 7, 1, 13, 
5, 5, 3, 3, 6, 10, 4, 11, 9, 2, 4, 3, 7, 7, 9, 7, 0, 1, 2, 7, 
7, 1, 1, 5, 8, 7, 1, 7, 0, 0, 0, 2, 8, 5, 2, 7, 5, 0, 2, 1, 4, 
2, 5, 13, 4, 1, 1, 7, 5, 0, 2, 3, 2, 7, 0, 5, 2, 13, 2, 15, 1, 
1, 4, 7, 4, 2, 6, 2, 1, 6, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 4, 3, 0, 3, 
8, 1, 4, 7, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4, 0, 6, 2, 5, 0, 1, 3, 1, 1, 0, 4, 9, 
3, 8, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 5, 3, 5, 2, 10, 4, 0, 9, 2, 5, 2, 1, 4, 
9, 1, 8, 7, 2, 1, 2, 17, 4, 7, 0, 2, 0, 6, 3, 4, 4, 3, 6, 6, 
2, 1, 2, 8, 6, 0, 5, 5, 6, 0, 1, 5, 4, 7, 8, 1, 8, 5, 3, 9, 7, 
11, 8, 5, 1, 3, 4, 4, 0, 1, 0, 2, 6, 5, 8, 5, 1, 7, 2, 0, 7, 
0, 9, 12, 5, 6, 5, 5, 0, 2, 7, 7, 1, 1, 0, 3, 4, 0, 4, 6, 1, 
4, 3, 4, 7, 0, 9, 0, 1, 4, 3, 6, 2, 9, 10, 0, 9, 1, 9, 2, 2, 
0, 12, 1, 3, 2, 1, 11, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 0, 2, 0, 2, 10, 2, 3, 
1, 13, 2, 7, 0, 5, 2, 0, 10, 7, 7, 2, 7, 5, 1, 4, 5, 0, 0, 2, 
1, 0, 6, 2, 0, 14, 8, 0, 2, 5, 5, 3, 2, 10, 0, 0, 2, 6, 0, 2, 
3, 7, 2, 3, 3, 3, 6, 4, 3, 0, 13, 2, 1, 1, 10, 2, 6, 8, 2, 1, 
12, 1, 0, 0, 5, 9, 7, 1, 1, 1, 5, 8, 8, 1, 3, 3, 5, 4, 4, 3, 
1, 3, 9, 1, 13, 12, 1, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 5, 6, 0, 3, 1, 3, 0, 0, 
2, 2, 12, 0, 1, 4, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1), Glucose = c(148, 85, 183, 
89, 137, 116, 78, 115, 197, 125, 110, 168, 139, 189, 166, 100, 
118, 107, 103, 115, 126, 99, 196, 119, 143, 125, 147, 97, 145, 
117, 109, 158, 88, 92, 122, 103, 138, 102, 90, 111, 180, 133, 
106, 171, 159, 180, 146, 71, 103, 105, 103, 101, 88, 176, 150, 
73, 187, 100, 146, 105, 84, 133, 44, 141, 114, 99, 109, 109, 
95, 146, 100, 139, 126, 129, 79, 0, 62, 95, 131, 112, 113, 74, 
83, 101, 137, 110, 106, 100, 136, 107, 80, 123, 81, 134, 142, 
144, 92, 71, 93, 122, 163, 151, 125, 81, 85, 126, 96, 144, 83, 
95, 171, 155, 89, 76, 160, 146, 124, 78, 97, 99, 162, 111, 107, 
132, 113, 88, 120, 118, 117, 105, 173, 122, 170, 84, 96, 125, 
100, 93, 129, 105, 128, 106, 108, 108, 154, 102, 57, 106, 147, 
90, 136, 114, 156, 153, 188, 152, 99, 109, 88, 163, 151, 102, 
114, 100, 131, 104, 148, 120, 110, 111, 102, 134, 87, 79, 75, 
179, 85, 129, 143, 130, 87, 119, 0, 73, 141, 194, 181, 128, 109, 
139, 111, 123, 159, 135, 85, 158, 105, 107, 109, 148, 113, 138, 
108, 99, 103, 111, 196, 162, 96, 184, 81, 147, 179, 140, 112, 
151, 109, 125, 85, 112, 177, 158, 119, 142, 100, 87, 101, 162, 
197, 117, 142, 134, 79, 122, 74, 171, 181, 179, 164, 104, 91, 
91, 139, 119, 146, 184, 122, 165, 124, 111, 106, 129, 90, 86, 
92, 113, 111, 114, 193, 155, 191, 141, 95, 142, 123, 96, 138, 
128, 102, 146, 101, 108, 122, 71, 106, 100, 106, 104, 114, 108, 
146, 129, 133, 161, 108, 136, 155, 119, 96, 108, 78, 107, 128, 
128, 161, 151, 146, 126, 100, 112, 167, 144, 77, 115, 150, 120, 
161, 137, 128, 124, 80, 106, 155, 113, 109, 112, 99, 182, 115, 
194, 129, 112, 124, 152, 112, 157, 122, 179, 102, 105, 118, 87, 
180, 106, 95, 165, 117, 115, 152, 178, 130, 95, 0, 122, 95, 126, 
139, 116, 99, 0, 92, 137, 61, 90, 90, 165, 125, 129, 88, 196, 
189, 158, 103, 146, 147, 99, 124, 101, 81, 133, 173, 118, 84, 
105, 122, 140, 98, 87, 156, 93, 107, 105, 109, 90), BloodPressure = c(72, 
66, 64, 66, 40, 74, 50, 0, 70, 96, 92, 74, 80, 60, 72, 0, 84, 
74, 30, 70, 88, 84, 90, 80, 94, 70, 76, 66, 82, 92, 75, 76, 58, 
92, 78, 60, 76, 76, 68, 72, 64, 84, 92, 110, 64, 66, 56, 70, 
66, 0, 80, 50, 66, 90, 66, 50, 68, 88, 82, 64, 0, 72, 62, 58, 
66, 74, 88, 92, 66, 85, 66, 64, 90, 86, 75, 48, 78, 72, 0, 66, 
44, 0, 78, 65, 108, 74, 72, 68, 70, 68, 55, 80, 78, 72, 82, 72, 
62, 48, 50, 90, 72, 60, 96, 72, 65, 56, 122, 58, 58, 85, 72, 
62, 76, 62, 54, 92, 74, 48, 60, 76, 76, 64, 74, 80, 76, 30, 70, 
58, 88, 84, 70, 56, 64, 74, 68, 60, 70, 60, 80, 72, 78, 82, 52, 
66, 62, 75, 80, 64, 78, 70, 74, 65, 86, 82, 78, 88, 52, 56, 74, 
72, 90, 74, 80, 64, 88, 74, 66, 68, 66, 90, 82, 70, 0, 60, 64, 
72, 78, 110, 78, 82, 80, 64, 74, 60, 74, 68, 68, 98, 76, 80, 
62, 70, 66, 0, 55, 84, 58, 62, 64, 60, 80, 82, 68, 70, 72, 72, 
76, 104, 64, 84, 60, 85, 95, 65, 82, 70, 62, 68, 74, 66, 60, 
90, 0, 60, 66, 78, 76, 52, 70, 80, 86, 80, 80, 68, 68, 72, 84, 
90, 84, 76, 64, 70, 54, 50, 76, 85, 68, 90, 70, 86, 52, 84, 80, 
68, 62, 64, 56, 68, 50, 76, 68, 0, 70, 80, 62, 74, 0, 64, 52, 
0, 86, 62, 78, 78, 70, 70, 60, 64, 74, 62, 70, 76, 88, 86, 80, 
74, 84, 86, 56, 72, 88, 62, 78, 48, 50, 62, 70, 84, 78, 72, 0, 
58, 82, 98, 76, 76, 68, 68, 68, 68, 66, 70, 74, 50, 80, 68, 80, 
74, 66, 78, 60, 74, 70, 90, 75, 72, 64, 70, 86, 70, 72, 58, 0, 
80, 60, 76, 0, 76, 78, 84, 70, 74, 68, 86, 72, 88, 46, 0, 62, 
80, 80, 84, 82, 62, 78, 88, 50, 0, 74, 76, 64, 70, 108, 78, 74, 
54, 72, 64, 86, 102, 82, 64, 64, 58, 52, 82, 82, 60, 75, 100, 
72, 68, 60, 62), SkinThickness = c(35, 29, 0, 23, 35, 0, 32, 
0, 45, 0, 0, 0, 0, 23, 19, 0, 47, 0, 38, 30, 41, 0, 0, 35, 33, 
26, 0, 15, 19, 0, 26, 36, 11, 0, 31, 33, 0, 37, 42, 47, 25, 0, 
18, 24, 0, 39, 0, 27, 32, 0, 11, 15, 21, 34, 42, 10, 39, 60, 
0, 41, 0, 0, 0, 34, 0, 27, 30, 0, 13, 27, 20, 35, 0, 20, 30, 
20, 0, 33, 0, 22, 13, 0, 26, 28, 0, 29, 54, 25, 32, 19, 0, 15, 
40, 0, 18, 27, 28, 18, 30, 51, 0, 0, 0, 18, 0, 29, 0, 28, 31, 
25, 33, 26, 34, 0, 32, 0, 0, 0, 23, 15, 56, 39, 30, 0, 0, 42, 
30, 36, 24, 0, 14, 0, 37, 31, 13, 20, 26, 25, 0, 29, 0, 30, 26, 
0, 31, 23, 37, 35, 0, 17, 50, 0, 28, 42, 0, 44, 15, 21, 19, 41, 
38, 40, 34, 23, 0, 18, 25, 0, 0, 12, 0, 23, 23, 42, 24, 42, 0, 
46, 0, 0, 0, 18, 20, 0, 0, 28, 36, 41, 39, 35, 0, 44, 0, 0, 20, 
41, 0, 13, 44, 27, 16, 0, 20, 16, 32, 28, 29, 0, 27, 33, 22, 
54, 31, 26, 32, 40, 41, 30, 22, 0, 29, 0, 0, 33, 15, 27, 0, 38, 
39, 31, 0, 37, 25, 0, 28, 0, 21, 27, 21, 0, 24, 32, 0, 22, 35, 
15, 0, 33, 33, 19, 0, 0, 14, 32, 7, 35, 39, 22, 16, 28, 15, 0, 
32, 15, 0, 18, 0, 42, 0, 0, 37, 32, 0, 50, 0, 52, 24, 23, 0, 
10, 0, 28, 15, 0, 0, 26, 44, 39, 17, 43, 29, 30, 37, 45, 0, 31, 
38, 29, 25, 0, 0, 33, 41, 0, 0, 37, 23, 14, 19, 28, 30, 37, 17, 
10, 31, 22, 11, 0, 39, 0, 12, 30, 20, 33, 32, 21, 32, 0, 36, 
32, 19, 16, 0, 0, 18, 43, 0, 0, 34, 0, 13, 21, 35, 0, 0, 36, 
19, 0, 19, 32, 0, 0, 28, 12, 0, 0, 40, 30, 40, 36, 33, 0, 37, 
0, 25, 28, 0, 17, 16, 28, 48, 23, 22, 40, 43, 43, 15, 37, 0, 
39, 30, 22, 8, 18), Insulin = c(0, 0, 0, 94, 168, 0, 88, 0, 543, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 846, 175, 0, 230, 0, 83, 96, 235, 0, 0, 0, 146, 115, 
0, 140, 110, 0, 0, 245, 54, 0, 0, 192, 0, 0, 0, 207, 70, 0, 0, 
240, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 82, 36, 23, 300, 342, 0, 304, 110, 0, 
142, 0, 0, 0, 128, 0, 0, 0, 0, 38, 100, 90, 140, 0, 270, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 71, 0, 0, 125, 0, 71, 110, 0, 0, 176, 48, 0, 
64, 228, 0, 76, 64, 220, 0, 0, 0, 40, 0, 152, 0, 140, 18, 36, 
135, 495, 37, 0, 175, 0, 0, 0, 0, 51, 100, 0, 100, 0, 0, 99, 
135, 94, 145, 0, 168, 0, 225, 0, 49, 140, 50, 92, 0, 325, 0, 
0, 63, 0, 284, 0, 0, 119, 0, 0, 204, 0, 155, 485, 0, 0, 94, 135, 
53, 114, 0, 105, 285, 0, 0, 156, 0, 0, 0, 78, 0, 130, 0, 48, 
55, 130, 0, 130, 0, 0, 0, 92, 23, 0, 0, 0, 495, 58, 114, 160, 
0, 94, 0, 0, 0, 210, 0, 48, 99, 318, 0, 0, 0, 44, 190, 0, 280, 
0, 87, 0, 0, 0, 0, 130, 175, 271, 129, 120, 0, 0, 478, 0, 0, 
190, 56, 32, 0, 0, 744, 53, 0, 370, 37, 0, 45, 0, 192, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 88, 0, 176, 194, 0, 0, 680, 402, 0, 0, 0, 55, 0, 258, 0, 
0, 0, 375, 150, 130, 0, 0, 0, 0, 67, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 56, 0, 45, 
0, 57, 0, 116, 0, 278, 0, 122, 155, 0, 0, 135, 545, 220, 49, 
75, 40, 74, 182, 194, 0, 120, 360, 215, 184, 0, 0, 135, 42, 0, 
0, 105, 132, 148, 180, 205, 0, 148, 96, 85, 0, 94, 64, 0, 140, 
0, 231, 0, 0, 29, 0, 168, 156, 0, 120, 68, 0, 52, 0, 0, 58, 255, 
0, 0, 171, 0, 105, 73, 0, 0, 0, 108, 83, 0, 74, 0, 0, 0, 0, 43, 
0, 0, 167, 0, 54, 249, 325, 0, 0, 0, 293, 83, 0, 0, 66, 140, 
465, 89, 66, 94, 158, 325, 84, 75, 0, 72, 82, 0, 182, 59), BMI = c(33.6, 
26.6, 23.3, 28.1, 43.1, 25.6, 31, 35.3, 30.5, 0, 37.6, 38, 27.1, 
30.1, 25.8, 30, 45.8, 29.6, 43.3, 34.6, 39.3, 35.4, 39.8, 29, 
36.6, 31.1, 39.4, 23.2, 22.2, 34.1, 36, 31.6, 24.8, 19.9, 27.6, 
24, 33.2, 32.9, 38.2, 37.1, 34, 40.2, 22.7, 45.4, 27.4, 42, 29.7, 
28, 39.1, 0, 19.4, 24.2, 24.4, 33.7, 34.7, 23, 37.7, 46.8, 40.5, 
41.5, 0, 32.9, 25, 25.4, 32.8, 29, 32.5, 42.7, 19.6, 28.9, 32.9, 
28.6, 43.4, 35.1, 32, 24.7, 32.6, 37.7, 43.2, 25, 22.4, 0, 29.3, 
24.6, 48.8, 32.4, 36.6, 38.5, 37.1, 26.5, 19.1, 32, 46.7, 23.8, 
24.7, 33.9, 31.6, 20.4, 28.7, 49.7, 39, 26.1, 22.5, 26.6, 39.6, 
28.7, 22.4, 29.5, 34.3, 37.4, 33.3, 34, 31.2, 34, 30.5, 31.2, 
34, 33.7, 28.2, 23.2, 53.2, 34.2, 33.6, 26.8, 33.3, 55, 42.9, 
33.3, 34.5, 27.9, 29.7, 33.3, 34.5, 38.3, 21.1, 33.8, 30.8, 28.7, 
31.2, 36.9, 21.1, 39.5, 32.5, 32.4, 32.8, 0, 32.8, 30.5, 33.7, 
27.3, 37.4, 21.9, 34.3, 40.6, 47.9, 50, 24.6, 25.2, 29, 40.9, 
29.7, 37.2, 44.2, 29.7, 31.6, 29.9, 32.5, 29.6, 31.9, 28.4, 30.8, 
35.4, 28.9, 43.5, 29.7, 32.7, 31.2, 67.1, 45, 39.1, 23.2, 34.9, 
27.7, 26.8, 27.6, 35.9, 30.1, 32, 27.9, 31.6, 22.6, 33.1, 30.4, 
52.3, 24.4, 39.4, 24.3, 22.9, 34.8, 30.9, 31, 40.1, 27.3, 20.4, 
37.7, 23.9, 37.5, 37.7, 33.2, 35.5, 27.7, 42.8, 34.2, 42.6, 34.2, 
41.8, 35.8, 30, 29, 37.8, 34.6, 31.6, 25.2, 28.8, 23.6, 34.6, 
35.7, 37.2, 36.7, 45.2, 44, 46.2, 25.4, 35, 29.7, 43.6, 35.9, 
44.1, 30.8, 18.4, 29.2, 33.1, 25.6, 27.1, 38.2, 30, 31.2, 52.3, 
35.4, 30.1, 31.2, 28, 24.4, 35.8, 27.6, 33.6, 30.1, 28.7, 25.9, 
33.3, 30.9, 30, 32.1, 32.4, 32, 33.6, 36.3, 40, 25.1, 27.5, 45.6, 
25.2, 23, 33.2, 34.2, 40.5, 26.5, 27.8, 24.9, 25.3, 37.9, 35.9, 
32.4, 30.4, 27, 26, 38.7, 45.6, 20.8, 36.1, 36.9, 36.6, 43.3, 
40.5, 21.9, 35.5, 28, 30.7, 36.6, 23.6, 32.3, 31.6, 35.8, 52.9, 
21, 39.7, 25.5, 24.8, 30.5, 32.9, 26.2, 39.4, 26.6, 29.5, 35.9, 
34.1, 19.3, 30.5, 38.1, 23.5, 27.5, 31.6, 27.4, 26.8, 35.7, 25.6, 
35.1, 35.1, 45.5, 30.8, 23.1, 32.7, 43.3, 23.6, 23.9, 47.9, 33.8, 
31.2, 34.2, 39.9, 25.9, 25.9, 32, 34.7, 36.8, 38.5, 28.7, 23.5, 
21.8, 41, 42.2, 31.2, 34.4, 27.2, 42.7, 30.4, 33.3, 39.9, 35.3, 
36.5, 31.2, 29.8, 39.2, 38.5, 34.9, 34, 27.6, 21, 27.5, 32.8, 
38.4, 0, 35.8, 34.9, 36.2, 39.2, 25.2, 37.2, 48.3, 43.4, 30.8, 
20, 25.4, 25.1), DiabetesPedigreeFunction = c(0.627, 0.351, 0.672, 
0.167, 2.288, 0.201, 0.248, 0.134, 0.158, 0.232, 0.191, 0.537, 
1.441, 0.398, 0.587, 0.484, 0.551, 0.254, 0.183, 0.529, 0.704, 
0.388, 0.451, 0.263, 0.254, 0.205, 0.257, 0.487, 0.245, 0.337, 
0.546, 0.851, 0.267, 0.188, 0.512, 0.966, 0.42, 0.665, 0.503, 
1.39, 0.271, 0.696, 0.235, 0.721, 0.294, 1.893, 0.564, 0.586, 
0.344, 0.305, 0.491, 0.526, 0.342, 0.467, 0.718, 0.248, 0.254, 
0.962, 1.781, 0.173, 0.304, 0.27, 0.587, 0.699, 0.258, 0.203, 
0.855, 0.845, 0.334, 0.189, 0.867, 0.411, 0.583, 0.231, 0.396, 
0.14, 0.391, 0.37, 0.27, 0.307, 0.14, 0.102, 0.767, 0.237, 0.227, 
0.698, 0.178, 0.324, 0.153, 0.165, 0.258, 0.443, 0.261, 0.277, 
0.761, 0.255, 0.13, 0.323, 0.356, 0.325, 1.222, 0.179, 0.262, 
0.283, 0.93, 0.801, 0.207, 0.287, 0.336, 0.247, 0.199, 0.543, 
0.192, 0.391, 0.588, 0.539, 0.22, 0.654, 0.443, 0.223, 0.759, 
0.26, 0.404, 0.186, 0.278, 0.496, 0.452, 0.261, 0.403, 0.741, 
0.361, 1.114, 0.356, 0.457, 0.647, 0.088, 0.597, 0.532, 0.703, 
0.159, 0.268, 0.286, 0.318, 0.272, 0.237, 0.572, 0.096, 1.4, 
0.218, 0.085, 0.399, 0.432, 1.189, 0.687, 0.137, 0.337, 0.637, 
0.833, 0.229, 0.817, 0.294, 0.204, 0.167, 0.368, 0.743, 0.722, 
0.256, 0.709, 0.471, 0.495, 0.18, 0.542, 0.773, 0.678, 0.37, 
0.719, 0.382, 0.319, 0.19, 0.956, 0.084, 0.725, 0.299, 0.268, 
0.244, 0.745, 0.615, 1.321, 0.64, 0.361, 0.142, 0.374, 0.383, 
0.578, 0.136, 0.395, 0.187, 0.678, 0.905, 0.15, 0.874, 0.236, 
0.787, 0.235, 0.324, 0.407, 0.605, 0.151, 0.289, 0.355, 0.29, 
0.375, 0.164, 0.431, 0.26, 0.742, 0.514, 0.464, 1.224, 0.261, 
1.072, 0.805, 0.209, 0.687, 0.666, 0.101, 0.198, 0.652, 2.329, 
0.089, 0.645, 0.238, 0.583, 0.394, 0.293, 0.479, 0.586, 0.686, 
0.831, 0.582, 0.192, 0.446, 0.402, 1.318, 0.329, 1.213, 0.258, 
0.427, 0.282, 0.143, 0.38, 0.284, 0.249, 0.238, 0.926, 0.543, 
0.557, 0.092, 0.655, 1.353, 0.299, 0.761, 0.612, 0.2, 0.226, 
0.997, 0.933, 1.101, 0.078, 0.24, 1.136, 0.128, 0.254, 0.422, 
0.251, 0.677, 0.296, 0.454, 0.744, 0.881, 0.334, 0.28, 0.262, 
0.165, 0.259, 0.647, 0.619, 0.808, 0.34, 0.263, 0.434, 0.757, 
1.224, 0.613, 0.254, 0.692, 0.337, 0.52, 0.412, 0.84, 0.839, 
0.422, 0.156, 0.209, 0.207, 0.215, 0.326, 0.143, 1.391, 0.875, 
0.313, 0.605, 0.433, 0.626, 1.127, 0.315, 0.284, 0.345, 0.15, 
0.129, 0.527, 0.197, 0.254, 0.731, 0.148, 0.123, 0.692, 0.2, 
0.127, 0.122, 1.476, 0.166, 0.282, 0.137, 0.26, 0.259, 0.932, 
0.343, 0.893, 0.331, 0.472, 0.673, 0.389, 0.29, 0.485, 0.349, 
0.654, 0.187, 0.279, 0.346, 0.237, 0.252, 0.243, 0.58, 0.559, 
0.302, 0.962, 0.569, 0.378, 0.875, 0.583, 0.207, 0.305, 0.52, 
0.385, 0.499, 0.368, 0.252, 0.306, 0.234, 2.137, 1.731, 0.545, 
0.225, 0.816, 0.528, 0.299, 0.509, 0.238, 1.021, 0.821, 0.236, 
0.947, 1.268), Age = c(50, 31, 32, 21, 33, 30, 26, 29, 53, 54, 
30, 34, 57, 59, 51, 32, 31, 31, 33, 32, 27, 50, 41, 29, 51, 41, 
43, 22, 57, 38, 60, 28, 22, 28, 45, 33, 35, 46, 27, 56, 26, 37, 
48, 54, 40, 25, 29, 22, 31, 24, 22, 26, 30, 58, 42, 21, 41, 31, 
44, 22, 21, 39, 36, 24, 42, 32, 38, 54, 25, 27, 28, 26, 42, 23, 
22, 22, 41, 27, 26, 24, 22, 22, 36, 22, 37, 27, 45, 26, 43, 24, 
21, 34, 42, 60, 21, 40, 24, 22, 23, 31, 33, 22, 21, 24, 27, 21, 
27, 37, 25, 24, 24, 46, 23, 25, 39, 61, 38, 25, 22, 21, 25, 24, 
23, 69, 23, 26, 30, 23, 40, 62, 33, 33, 30, 39, 26, 31, 21, 22, 
29, 28, 55, 38, 22, 42, 23, 21, 41, 34, 65, 22, 24, 37, 42, 23, 
43, 36, 21, 23, 22, 47, 36, 45, 27, 21, 32, 41, 22, 34, 29, 29, 
36, 29, 25, 23, 33, 36, 42, 26, 47, 37, 32, 23, 21, 27, 40, 41, 
60, 33, 31, 25, 21, 40, 36, 40, 42, 29, 21, 23, 26, 29, 21, 28, 
32, 27, 55, 27, 57, 52, 21, 41, 25, 24, 60, 24, 36, 38, 25, 32, 
32, 41, 21, 66, 37, 61, 26, 22, 26, 24, 31, 24, 22, 46, 22, 29, 
23, 26, 51, 23, 32, 27, 21, 22, 22, 33, 29, 49, 41, 23, 34, 23, 
42, 27, 24, 25, 44, 21, 30, 25, 24, 51, 34, 27, 24, 63, 35, 43, 
25, 24, 21, 28, 38, 21, 40, 21, 52, 25, 29, 23, 57, 22, 28, 39, 
37, 47, 52, 51, 34, 29, 26, 33, 21, 25, 31, 24, 65, 28, 29, 24, 
46, 58, 30, 25, 35, 28, 37, 29, 47, 21, 25, 30, 41, 22, 27, 25, 
43, 26, 30, 29, 28, 59, 31, 25, 36, 43, 21, 24, 30, 37, 23, 37, 
46, 25, 41, 44, 22, 26, 44, 44, 33, 41, 22, 36, 22, 33, 57, 49, 
22, 23, 26, 37, 29, 30, 46, 24, 21, 49, 28, 44, 48, 29, 29, 63, 
65, 67, 30, 30, 29, 21, 22, 45, 25, 21, 21, 25, 28, 58, 22, 22, 
32, 35, 24, 22, 21, 25), Outcome = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
-384L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


you should look into what a confusionmatrix is, then you will understand why the command throws an error.

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Questions do better with a reproducible example. Having said that, it appears from your output that logitresp is continuous and actual is binary. You can't create a confusion matrix from this. Did you create logitresp with caret::extractProb()? If so you probably want caret::extractPrediction(). If you include code to generate predictions from sample data, I suspect you'll quickly get an answer showing how to resolve this.

I added logit's definition and dput(training_data), thanks!

Its already stated that the two data are different. One is integer/binary the other is double. You cannot create a confusion matrix from that. Thats why I adviced that you should revisit what a confusion matrix is. Perhaps consider confusionMatrix(data=logitresp > 0.5, reference=actual) or since you have the model  confusionMatrix(actual, round(predict(logit, type='response')))

@Onyambu, I apologize, yes this makes sense now, thanks!

I switched logitesp to binary and the code throws the same error, does CM not take binary predictions and references?

I do not know what package you are using etc. Simply create a confusion matrix using table function in base R. ie table(actual, as.numeric(logitresp > 0.5))

I'm primarily using CM to find the number of correct positives, false positives, correct negatives, and false negatives. Given I'm comparing a double probability to a binary, is this completely misguided then? (Is converting this probability to a binary against the spirit  of CM)

Indeed. Note that you cannot compare probability to label. ie 1,0 are labels of a class while 0.948 is the probability of being in class 1. So you need to convert the labels to probability.

It appears from your error message you are using caret. Here is an example of how to create a confusion matrix with your data. Note that both predicted and reference vectors need to be a factor. In your data, the reference is binary but numeric, and the predicted data appears to be the logits rather than the predicted categories.
To resolve this, first prepare the data and train your model.
library(caret)

# Make factor
training_data$Outcome_fct  <- factor(training_data$Outcome)

# Train simple model
default_glm_mod = train(
  form = Outcome_fct ~ Glucose,
  data = training_data,
  trControl = trainControl(method = "none"),
  method = "glm",
  family = "binomial"
)

Then create the confusion matrix. Which class is positive does not matter for accuracy, but you will need to specify the positive class if you are going to use metrics like precision, recall and F1.
caret::confusionMatrix(
    data = predict(default_glm_mod),
    reference = training_data$Outcome_fct,
    positive = "1" # set positive class
)

Output:

Confusion Matrix and Statistics

          Reference
Prediction   0   1
         0 199  74
         1  40  71
                                          
               Accuracy : 0.7031          
                 95% CI : (0.6547, 0.7484)
    No Information Rate : 0.6224          
    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 0.0005585       
                                          
                  Kappa : 0.3379          
                                          
 Mcnemar's Test P-Value : 0.0019966       
                                          
            Sensitivity : 0.8326          
            Specificity : 0.4897          
         Pos Pred Value : 0.7289          
         Neg Pred Value : 0.6396          
             Prevalence : 0.6224          
         Detection Rate : 0.5182          
   Detection Prevalence : 0.7109          
      Balanced Accuracy : 0.6611          
                                          
       'Positive' Class : 0                                             

For more see the classification section of the caret chapter of R for Statistical Learning by David Dalpiaz.
